# Working on Android Studio Quiz Game, R.menu is broken

Tags: android, android-studio

I am in a coding class and Android Studio is the development environment we are using, I'm making a simple quiz game, and I'm having trouble with one line:

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_quiz, menu);

Everything is fine in the code, except it does not recognize menu even though I imported it in the activity. Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Comment: Please, share the piece of code that is failing o give some information about the error. Have youa file in res/menu called activity_quiz?

Comment: when hovering over the menu in R.menu, it says the it cannot resolve the symbol. I have a layout file named activity_quiz.xml, but there is no res/menu.

Comment: Create the folder menu inside res folder and put this file inside. This file (activity_quiz) has the correct xml code for a menu? can you post it?

Comment: When making the menu folder in res, what type of folder does it need to be? Also, is there a way i could post all of the code here without going over the character limit?

Comment: Edit your question, and put it as <code> to format it. It is a normal folder

Comment: Is there an easier way to contact you about this problem? I'm not the best with message boards and feeling sending images or doing a skype call would best help me understand.

Comment: Are you using that one line in `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: Yes I am. This is the code for it: 
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_result, menu);
        return true;
    }
}

Comment: Try adding returning this instead of true: `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` Also, What exactly do you mean by "it does not recognize the menu"? The menu just isn't showing up or are you getting a compilation error?

Comment: In R.menu.activity_quiz, the menu is red and it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'menu".

Comment: Your menu XML should be in a folder named "menu" inside your "res" folder structure... sorry just noticed the other comments describing this.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot. Build > Clean up project, then Build > rebuild project should fix it. or import com.yourproject.R